# Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Show that $R[x]$ has a subring $R'$ isomorphic to $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Show that $R[x]$ has a subring $R'$ isomorphic to $R$.

Let $\varphi : R[x] \to R$ be the evaluation map $f(x) \mapsto f(0)$. Then $\varphi$ is a surjective ring homomorphism and $\ker(\varphi)= \{f  \in R[x] \mid f(0)=0 \} = \langle x\rangle.$ Also by the first isomorphism theorem $R[x]/\ker(\phi) \cong R[x]/\langle x\rangle \cong R$.

The issue I have with this is that I don't think that $R[x]/\langle x\rangle$ is a subring of $R[x]$. It's a quotient ring with completely different elements than $R[x]$ even though it can be thougth as the constant polynoimals. Is there a way to make this more rigorous?

Comment: Take the elements of degree $\leq 0$.

Comment: I don't think you can make it rigorous, since, as you say a quotient space is different from a subspace. I'd try to characterize $R$ in $R[x]$ in some other way, like, the set of elements whose evaluations $f(a)$ are equal for every $a$

Comment: @Exodd Values is not a good way to characterize elements of $R[x]$. For example, in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x]$, the element $x^p-x$ has the same values as $0$ at all elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What does the quotient ring have to do with this? The constant polynomials form a subring which is trivially isomorphic to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to make this more rigorous is to look at the subring $R'$ of $R[x]$ that consists of the constant polynomials.

Normally, you'd write a constant polynomial just as $r$ (with $r$ an element of $R$), but that's bound to be confusing if you're attempting to make a distinction between the constant polynomials and the elements of $R$ itself. Therefore, I'll write a constant polynomial as $r x^0$.

So $R' = \{ r x^0 \;|\; r \in R\} \subset R[x]$. There is an obvious homomorphism $R \to R'$, sending $r$ to $r x^0$; and there is an obvious homomorphism $R' \to R$, sending $r x^0$ to $r$, which you can also see as the restriction of the evaluation-at-$0$ homomorphism $R[x] \to R$ that maps $f$ to $f(0)$.